# test failed on Connection refused: connect

Tags: selenium-webdriver, codeception, acceptance-testing

I am trying to use codeception test, but if I start it go it freezes and in console i see:

```
  [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException]
  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I find: it is problem with version of selenium, driver and used google chrome. But if I use any combination I still won't get through

- OK, i got throw, down below the comments, problem was with window defender. When i shut it down, test started but i got another problem.

Next problem is error: **[PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] Undefined index: ELEMENT**, by the log from mRemote i find that the problem is with line `$I->see('Stay signed');` if i delete it, error continue to another line which is `$I->fillField('#loginUsername', $name);`

method with problem:

```
public function login($name, $password)
```

{
    $I = $this;

```
// if snapshot exists - skipping login
if (method_exists($I, 'loadSessionSnapshot') && $I->loadSessionSnapshot('login')) {
    return;
}

// logging in
$I->wantTo('log in');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see('Stay signed'); // <---- here is problem
$I->fillField('#loginUsername', $name);
$I->fillField('#loginPassword', $password);
$I->click('Přihlásit se');


if (method_exists($I, 'waitForElement')) {
    $I->waitForElement('.header');
} else {
    $I->waitForPageLoad();
}

// saving snapshot
if (method_exists($I, 'saveSessionSnapshot')) {
    $I->saveSessionSnapshot('login');
}
```

}

The problem is with line "$I->see('Stay signed')", if i delete this line of code, error jumped on another line "$I->fillField..."

some tips what is wrong?

Comment: What command are you running and what does your functional.suite.yml (I assume) look like? Without that sort of information it's hard to say but I assume it's some sort of firewall issue.

Comment: @tschumann maybe it helped, but I got another problem, the window opens when I run the test and all the tests end up with an error: "Undefined index: ELEMENT". This will show me an error with Actor.php, but if I remove method with error, the error move on another method, some tip what´s of problem could it be?
eventually thx a lot for your first answer

Comment: Can you paste the source of the problematic method? I assume it's a PHP error?

Comment: @tschumann to long for this textfield, i put it as the answer down below

Comment: Do you have a longer stack trace? It looks like the error is probably in facebook/webdriver somewhere but there are a few places it could be by the looks of it.

Comment: @tschumann do you mean something like this: [PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] Undefined index: ELEMENT ?

Comment: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect" looks like Selenium's failure to connect to the browser.
"Undefined index: ELEMENT" is a red herring - `facebook/webdriver` doesn't handle unexpected responses well.  It would be the best to look at the logs or some debug output of Selenium.

Comment: thx a lot a manage it the problem was with facebook/driver.

Comment: Ok, it is local problem with company VNP, we solved the problem with technical support, but i really don´t know what was wrong... i think it is problem with time-to-live settings